# How can I retrieve relative humidity(%) from 3-Hourly GLDAS Dataset using Google Earth Engine for specific date?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, google-earth

I would like to calculate mean and instantaneous relative humidity for a specific location and date like 2018-08-18 at 10am. This is the script:

```
// Define the region of interest (Adana City Boundary)
var ROI = table.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM1_NAME', 'Adana'));

// Load the GLDAS dataset
var image = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/GLDAS/V021/NOAH/G025/T3H')
    .filterDate('2018-08-18', '2018-08-19');
    
// Define the expression to calculate relative humidity
  var RelativeHumidity = image.expression(
    '0.263 * p * q * (Math.exp(17.67 * (T - T0) / (T - 29.65))) ** -1', {
      T: image.select('Tair_f_inst'),
      T0: 273.16,
      p: image.select('Psurf_f_inst'),
      q: image.select('Qair_f_inst')
    }
  ).float();


// Calculate the mean relative humidity
var meanRelativeHumidity = RelativeHumidity.mean();

// Clip the result to the Adana City Boundary
var clippedResult = meanRelativeHumidity.clip(ROI);

// Visualize the result
Map.centerObject(adanaPolygon, 11); // Adjust the zoom level as needed
Map.addLayer(clippedResult, {
  min: 0,
  max: 100,
  palette: ['blue', 'purple', 'cyan', 'green', 'yellow', 'red'],
}, 'Mean Relative Humidity');

// Print the mean relative humidity to the console
print('Mean Relative Humidity:', clippedResult);
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/d38ed751f6d273a5e89123ec0a6e8427

I have error: Line 9: image.expression is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

The error is that you are trying to apply [ee.Image.expression](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-expression) to an object that is not `ee.Image`, but rather `ee.ImageCollection`. Let's rename the variable to reflect this on line 5:

```js
var imageCollection = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/GLDAS/V021/NOAH/G025/T3H')
    .filterDate('2018-08-18', '2018-08-19');
```

What you can do is wrap `ee.Image.expression` into a function that you then map to the image collection:

```js
// Define the expression to calculate relative humidity
function RH(image){
  return image.expression(
    '0.263 * p * q * (exp(17.67 * (T - T0) / (T - 29.65))) ** -1', {
      T: image.select('Tair_f_inst'),
      T0: 273.16,
      p: image.select('Psurf_f_inst'),
      q: image.select('Qair_f_inst')
    }
  ).float();
}

var RelativeHumidity = imageCollection.map(RH);
```

Note that later when you use `RelativeHumidity.mean()` the image collection is now reduced to `ee.Image`.

Also note that instead of `Math.exp`, you need to use `exp` directly, as explained in the comments within the code example given here https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-expression :

```js
// Expressions can use arithmetic operators (+ - * / % **), relational
// operators (== != < > <= >=), logical operators (&& || ! ^), the ternary
// operator (condition ? ifTrue : ifFalse), and a subset of JavaScript Math
// functions. Math functions are called by name directly, they are not accessed
// from the Math object (e.g., sqrt() instead of Math.sqrt()).
```

Here's the complete example:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/5e9ae0d7bb134c832382d3d5f0da31d4